# Snappy compressed file on HDFS appears without extension and is not readable

Tags: bash, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I configured a Map Reduce job to save output as a Sequence file compressed with Snappy. The MR job executes successfully however in HDFS the output file looks as the following:
[image]
I've expected that the file will have a .snappy extension and that it should be `part-r-00000.snappy`. And now I think that this may be the reason for the file to be not readable when I'm trying to read it from a local file system using this pattern `hadoop fs -libjars /path/to/jar/myjar.jar -text /path/in/HDFS/to/my/file` 
So I'm getting the `–libjars: Unknown command` when executing the command:

```
hadoop fs –libjars /root/hd/metrics.jar -text /user/maria_dev/hd/output/part-r-00000
```

And when I'm using this command  `hadoop fs -text /user/maria_dev/hd/output/part-r-00000`, I'm getting the error:

```
18/02/15 22:01:57 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
-text: Fatal internal error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: com.hd.metrics.IpMetricsWritable
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hd.ipmetrics.IpMetricsWritable not found
```

Could it be that the absence of the .snappy extension causes the problem? What other command should I try to read the compressed file?
The jar is in my local file system /root/hd/ Where should I place it not to cause ClassNotFoundException? Or how should I modify the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `hadoop fs –libjars` (which actually has a wrong  hyphen and should be `-libjars`. Copy that exactly, and you won't see `Unknown command`)

You should be using `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/root/hd/metrics.jar:${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}
hadoop fs -text /user/maria_dev/hd/output/part-r-*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped me to solve the problem. Could you also tell when is it possible to use just a single command without  `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable? I've seen many examples without exporting an environment variable and wonder how this may be achieved.

Comment: You can put the bash variable on the same line or you can edit the hadoop-env.sh file to permanently add the JAR to the classpath

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says `ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hd.ipmetrics.IpMetricsWritable not found`.

It means that a required library is missing in classpath.
To clarify your doubts:

1. Map-Reduce by default output the file as part-* and there is no
   meaning of extension. Remember extension "thing" is just a metadata
   usually required by windows operating system to determine suitable
   program for the file. It has no meaning in linux/unix and the
   system's behavior is not going to change, even though you rename the
   file as .snappy (you may actually try this).
2. The command looks absolutely fine to inspect the snappy file, but it seems that some required jar file are not there, which is causing `ClassNotFoundException`.

EDIT 1:
By default hadoop picks the jar files from the path emit by below command:

```
$ hadoop classpath
```

By default it list all the hadoop core jars.

You can add your jar by executing below command on the prompt

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/my/custom.jar
```

After executing this, try checking the class path again by `hadoop classpath` command and you should be able to see your jar listed along with hadoop core jars.

Comment: The jar is in my local file system /root/hd/ Where should I place it not to cause `ClassNotFoundException`? Or how should I modify the command? When I'm trying to execute this comand `hadoop fs –libjars /root/hd/metrics.jar -text /user/maria_dev/hd/output/part-r-00000` indicating a path to the jar, I'm getting `–libjars: Unknown command` as mentioned before.

Comment: Added more details in the original answer. Hope it helps.